# What framework is this website for?

Tags: frameworks, web

I have some files which are supposed to be the "code" for a website but I don't know which Framework it is for.

I have a "*.txt" file with nothing but JavaScript-like lines with double "$", like:

```
$setglobalvars(xpto,0)$
$setvars(xpto2,lookuptable(!MasterData,xpto3,xpto4,lookup(xpto5),LAST_NAME))$
```

And a few other "*.txt" HTML-template-like files (appears to be "Mustache" templates), like:

```
<script id="header_tag_tmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
            <div class="tmplHidden">
                <div class="pass_elem first">
                    <div class="fieldName">name</div>
                    <div class="field">{{:user.firstname}} {{:user.surname}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="pass_elem second" >
                    <div class="fieldName">level</div>
                    <div class="field">{{:user.level.currentName}}</div>
                </div><!--
                --><div class="pass_elem third">
                    <div class="fieldName">LEVEL EXPIRY</div>
                    {{if ((user.level.currentName) == 'Entry')}}
<div class="field">N/A</div>
                {{else}}    
                    <div class="field">{{:user.level.levelExpiry}}</div>
                {{/if}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
```

And also containing JavaScript-like lines completely outside SCRIPT tags or any other HTML tags:

```
$setvars(xpto,lookuptable(!MasterData,xpto2,xpto3,lookup(xpto4),xpto5))$
```

-

I am dealing with a 3rd party Software Provider, which created a website for my company (the source is supposed to be ours). They're being unpleasant to the point where we're considering seriously ditching them and now I need to take ownership over this website. However, I don't even know for sure which Framework the website is supposed to be.

Does anyone know what Framework this website is likely coded for?

Comment: This looks like it might be "JsRender" views: https://www.jsviews.com/ - currently investigation that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is being hosted by a proprietary web Framework (combined with JsRender).

The {{ tags are exactly the same as the ones for JsRender but those $something$ I just can't find out what they are and it's appearing me they're being processed by a proprietary framework.

This is not exactly a proper answer but I don't believe I'm going to get anything better than this.

*(and it appears we might have become vendor-locked in to them, which is why they're being so much at ease to treat us with commercial disrespect - lovely)*